# Laravel 5.4 and Wordpress integration on ubuntu nginx

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am not finding a complete guide on how to integrate a wordpress to a already deployed laravel application for a begginer on ubuntu 14.04 nginx server (I am using digital ocean ) to create a blog with it using subdomain like `example.com/blog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new folder named `blog` in your laravel public folder, and install wordpress into it.

Comment: after that what should i do

Comment: then you open example.com/blog and follow the installation guides ... that's it

Comment: are u saying that there is no serious configurations there. just extracting the worpress to blog folder will do the trick?

Comment: Yep... it's easier than it sounds :D

Comment: let me try then

Comment: dont you think its unsecure to put wordpress configuration file inside public folder

Comment: your wordpress stuff (configuration, etc) is in a separate folder `blog` ... why do you have concernes that it might be unsecure?

Comment: but the blog is in public folder

Comment: tell me what your concerns are.. so maybe I can argue on that. Otherwise mark the answer as checked and vote up, if it helped you.

Comment: please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007935/nginx-configuration-for-wordpress-into-laravel-application

Comment: i.e i have ssl configured. now i want wordpress to run as example.com/blog. but there is some nginx configuration

Comment: Unfortunately you can only mark one answer as correct :-)

Comment: please help me first

Comment: I also commented on your second stackoverflow question. So, let's mark this one as finished and resume there, because I assure you this one is correct what you've done. We just have to find out why nginx gives you a 403 error ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148776/discussion-between-ahmed-khan-and-ad-on-is).

Answer (score 0):

[Themosis](http://framework.themosis.com) is a really great way to integrate laravel with WordPress while still keeping the cool functionality from both.