# NGINX configuration for wordpress into laravel application

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am following [this digitalocean link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install wordpress with little modification. I have a laravel application installed and configured there and i followed all steps for directory `/var/www/laravel/public/blog/wordpress` (directory I installed wordpress into). Now I need help with configuring `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, So that i can have wordpress on `example.com/blog`. Uptill now I have just came up with
    `location /blog { 
            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }`

but this is giving me `403 forbidden`

Comment: do you have any log-outputs of nginx?

Comment: nope. found number of log files for nginx in nginx logs folder if these help??

Comment: yes, that's what we need

Comment: lets begin here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148776/discussion-between-ahmed-khan-and-ad-on-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our chat-conversation. You have to copy all your files and folders from `/blog/wordpress` to `/blog` if you want your blog to be accessible by `https://example.com/blog`